# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path

Tags: java, runtime-error, lwjgl

Whenever I try to run a Java program using LWJGL, I end up with this error or some permutation of it:

> `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl
>   in java.library.path  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)  at
>   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)  at
>   java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)    at
>   org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:73)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)  at
>   org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:95)    at
>   org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:112)  at
>   org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:135)   at
>   org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer$1.run(AppGameContainer.java:37)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.<clinit>(AppGameContainer.java:34)
>     at com.mojang.mojam.giraffe.Game.main(Game.java:220)`

I have tried entering 
-Djava.library.path="/Users/marcus888/Downloads/Giraffemacka/natives/" when running from commandline, but it still doesn't work. Help?

By the way, this doesn't have anything to do with the code of the program in question; this error happens for even full Java games like Minecraft.

Answer (score 3):

To fix the java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError in LWJGL:
use this piece of code:
`System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", "\lib_folder");`
replace "\lib_folder" with your natives/library's folder

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe your path should be quoted there.  Try using:

```
-Djava.library.path=/Users/marcus888/Downloads/Giraffemacka/natives/
```

Comment: OK, what is actually in the folder at /Users/marcus888/Downloads/Giraffemacka/natives/ ?

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/54826792/Screen%20Shot%202556-02-25%20at%204.19.34%20PM.png

Comment: That's not really helpful.  What I meant was, make sure that the version of LWJGL there matches what your OS needs (Linux vs OSX, or 32-bit vs 64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

For lack of mentioning which platform you are on and I realize this is an old post but I just had the same issue and resolved it so I wanted to add. I'm using windows, I had to copy and paste the filepath that the DLL files were actually in and that fixed it. It had to be exact including the drive letter for me to get it to work. so in my case it was (not under my main user path) "e:\LWJGL\lwjgl-2.9.3\natives\windows" (excluding the quotes unless you have spaces). Now it works fine.

Comment: Forward slashes in the path he tried would seem to indicate a platform other than Windows.

Comment: yea, and e:\ indicates it is Windows. But I prefer / because it's easier to type, but I'm used to \ for some strange reason.